# how to design db schema for if-else-then condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema, modeling

first of all, I am sorry in advance for my bad english. It would be difficult to understand what I'm trying to say, but I will try my best to explain what i want to ask.

**my question is how to design if-else-then condition db architecture. below is details.
**

I want to make kinda routing system based on user's answer. when I send inquiry form to user, and user answer the questions, then my system send the user to a link based on user's answer.

For example, there are two questions,

1. what's your age range?

- a. 20-30
- b. 30-40
- c. 40-50

2. what's your name?

and

if `question1's answer is a` or `question1's answer is b` then go to `A Link`

if `question1's answer is c` and `question2' answer contains 'kevin'` then go to `B Link`

I don't have any idea how to design db for those conditions.

I Have 2 models. but it is just temporary modeling.

```
routes

id | destination_type | destination_url  | rules            |
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | external_url     | https://a.com    | Idon't have idea |

// if user's answer matches with rules, then send user to destination_url
```

```
question

id | kind   | label                 | options                |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  | radio  | what's your age range | [{value: '20-30'},...] |
2  | name   | name                  | {}                     |
```

I want to design db table for rules but it would be ok if there is another idea other than designing db.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you want to have the rules within the database? That could help to provide better answers.

For the conditions you should have an idea which options you want to provide. It's pretty complicated to design a fully flexible rulebook in some lines of SQL

Comment: To make things easier you can google for "business rules engine" - doing so, i found this gem: https://github.com/azach/rules - perhaps it's what you are looking for

Comment: @zaphodbln_ Thank you so much for your reply!! I googled business rules engine and found https://github.com/ulfurinn/wongi-engine which looks like still under maintenance and works great. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think putting redirection links inside the database is breaking the MVC logic applied in rails.

Your condition formulated inside the text sounds like controller logic to me, e.g.

```
AnswerController
  def a
    if things
      redirect_to a_path
    else
      redirect_to b_path
    end
  end
end
```

But if you really try to make this fully dynamic a.k.a. full logic in database you can think about putting the medhod calls in the datebase as attribute `Question.my_string_on_answer_a` and work with `my_question.send(my_question.my_string_on_answer_a)` or redirect_to "my_string_on_answer_a" inside a `Controller` method or something.

Inn the end it sounds you like to put the routing targets in the database. Which is quite akward.

Sending something to `my_object` in ruby is like invoking/calling the method.

I used this lately to dynamically call methods. I had rows of a form implemented in a model. Tho "rows" could be called by `object.send("r123")` or `object.send("r54")`

calling methods accordingly e.g `object.r123` or `object.r54`

Your question is quite abstract. Sorry if my answer is too abstract for you to directly implement but at least should be food for thought! Happy to discuss further.

Please also think about that there are also boolean attributes in the database. Maybe this make things easier but 100% not sure.

Comment: @Juilan Thank you so much for your kind answer!! It was really helpful. thank you!!

Comment: @destiny1616 great that my answer helped you! Thought my answer might have been to academic or something. It would be super awesome if you would vote my answer up. Want to gain stackoverflow points because my votes are not accepted yet on stackoverflow due to lack of points! Thanks a ton!